# Assign dataset to aspxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-detail, aspxgridview

I have master detail aspxgridview. I have aspxcheckbox control and also check box column in master detail aspxgridview. On aspxcheckbox selection I want to select all rows in aspxgridview i.e master rows as well as detail rows. Previously I was calling aspxcheckbox_checkedChange event and on that event i was updating column in dataset and again assigning dataset but it doesnot work for me.

```
gridDocumentDetail.DataSource = dsGridData;
gridDocumentDetail.DataBind();
```

Comment: Are you sure there is any data in dsGridData? Could you provide its assignstatement?

Comment: Yes dsGridData has data with two tables. table[0] and table[1]. Because I have master detail relationship in aspxGridview.

Answer (score 0):

try this

gridDocumentDetail.DataSource = dsGridData.Tables[0];  //if you want you can pass index 1 according to your need

gridDocumentDetail.DataBind();

because datasource accept datatable 
where dataset contains many...

i hope this will work

Comment: But I have master detail relation. It should take dsGridData instead of dsGridData.Table[0].

Comment: If you want you can merge both into single table and use it...

because u cant pass dataset to datasource

Comment: I try but did not get the result what I want